# Using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015, Android emulator not working due to Java error

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to get the android emulator to work in VS however this error keeps popping up

```
Connection to the layout renderer failed. This may be caused by a misconfiguration of Java.
Details:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/utils/ILogger
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.utils.ILogger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
Exception in thread "main"
```